# Adding private PGP key to key ring

Tags: encryption, private-key, pgp

It is my understanding is if a file needs to be decrypted on my server I need to use a private key and give the party sending me the file the public key to encrypt it. The it's reversed if I am to encrypt a key. The other party provides me with their public key.

We have files that we encrypt using a public key ring. We have one public key ring that we use to encrypt files with. However, I see that there are two different secret key rings that are used to decyrpt files. One secret key ring decrypts a certain set of files and a second key ring decrypts another set.
Recently I've been working a project with two companies, A and B, where company A is playing the middle man.

Company A generated a key pair and sent the public key to Company B and me the private key. The private key was sent as a txt file. At this point I'm unsure what to do with the txt file as it was my understanding that it should be me that generated the public/private key pairing OR provide Company B with the public key that was already generated.
Do I name the txt file to have an asc exentsion  and run a command like:

```
PGP --pgppath e:\pgp\pgp.cfg -- secring e:\pgp\secring.pkr --key-add gdsecring.asc
```

Is that even possible? Or does it have to be a separate private key? If so do I just rename the private key to gdsecring.skr?

Any direction would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Open the key text file with a text editor and if it starts with this line

`----- BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY ------`

then just import into PGP:

```
pgp --import <keyname.txt>
```

(Note: probably in addition to the private key you will have to receive its password from Company A)

Comment: Which key ring would this be added to? We have two skr rings. PGP only exists in production. So the testing will have to be done in production. So as to not affect the encrypting and decrypting of current files, a back up of the PGP folder was done. As part of this project a public key was provided by Company C and was added to the public key ring in the backed up PGP folder. Is there a way to indicate the private key should be added the private key ring but only in the backed up PGP folder?

Answer (score 1):

I did some more research into this and found that you cannot add a private key to the key ring. From what I understand a vendor shouldn't generate a private/public key, send the public key to another vendor who will be encrypting the files and the private key to a different vendor who is decrypting it. We had to either generate a private/public key pairing and provide the vendor with our public key for encryption. OR send an existing public key which is what I did.